# XFS on-disk format upgrade

Tags: linux, debian, xfs

Is there any other way to upgrade an already formatted xfs v4 on-disk format partition to a xfs v5 without a back up-reformat-restore process? This was a result of creating the partitions using debian 8 installer (years ago), and then upgrading to debian 9 (some time ago as well). And now I need the reflink feature...

I need an inplace upgrade. I know the back up step is unavoidable (to have a fallback in case of trouble), but I want to minimize downtime as far as I can.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible, although it's also hard to find documentation that explicitely states it to be so. `xfs_db`'s `version` command seems close, but it can only set optional feature bits in V4, not magically change to V5 (and those are shorthanded into `xfs_admin`, and it seems like if enabling crc/reflink was a thing, it would also be in there).